# Query with successive conditions in where statement

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I am looking to get results from SQL Server database with below query using different filters:

```
select * from mytable where cond1 and cond2 and cond3 ... condn
```

But the condition must be successive:

- ( `cond1` true and `cond` x false) give me results for `cond1`
- ( `cond1` true and `cond2` true and `cond` x false) give me results for `cond1` and `cond2`
- ( `cond1` true and `cond2` true and `cond3` and `cond` x false) give me results for `cond1` and `cond2` and `cond3`

**example**

I want result form table product with filter `year - date - category1 - category2 - country - city - client`. If *country* and *city* equals `''` or `null`, then query must give results of `year date category1 category2 client`.

Comment: SQL is a special-purpose, declarative language. As such when a command is declared its structure (tables, fields, etc.) is immutable, though underlying values can be dynamic. You cannot conditionally set a `SELECT` column based on values in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: You need application layer code like PHP to build the structural components of SQL statement conditionally. Though tagged, I see no PHP code here.

Comment: the problem i have just possibility to make sql query
i work with scriptcase RAD tool